# Mac OS X search and replace tool with regular expression support

Tags: macos, mac, search, grep

I'm looking for a regular expression based search/replace GUI tool that is able to handle multiple files/subdirectories, something like [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin) but for Mac OS X.

PS. I'm aware of grep and I don't need an editor, just a standalone tool.

Comment: Komodo Edit (http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) has a "Find/Replace In Files" feature. Its a free editor for Mac, Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I also just found this:

http://www.dprog.ch/home/products/find_and_replace_it/

> About Find & Replace It!
>
> A powerful
>   search and replace utility. It allows
>   performing very complex batch
>   replacements inside text files of any
>   size. It supports regular expression
>   syntax and dozens of encodings. It has
>   scripting capabilities which allow
>   transforming on the fly the
>   replacement text for every found
>   string. It even handles batch
>   processing of the encoding of files,
>   as well as of types of end-of-lines.
>
> Here are some key features of Find &
>   Replace It!:
>
> - Find and replace across many files at once
> - **Supports regexps**
> - Supports many text encodings
> - Provides a regexp editor
> - Provides a find & replace preview
> - Offers a scripting interface that allows to transform replacement text
>     on the fly
> - Many more features

It's developed by [dProg - Philippe Docourt](http://www.dprog.ch/). **I've never used it**, so take this reccomendation with a grain of salt!

Comment: The links are broken

Comment: @AsafM this answer is over 7 years old. These days I would reccomend an IDE like VS Code, IntelliJ, BBEdit, or just use the command like. See my other answer.

Answer (score 14):

You're probably looking for a GUI app, but I can reccomend a terminal command. Perl can do inline replacement:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e "s/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g" {} \;
```

This will find all files under the current directory and replace based on the provided regexp. If you need to change directories, an easy way is to type: <kbd>cd</kbd>     (be sure there's a space after) and then drag and drop a folder from the Finder onto the terminal window. Press return and you'll be in the folder you want; then run the perl command above.

If you want perl to make backup copies before replacing, run:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i.bak -e "s/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g" {} \;
```

Comment: any time I suggest Perl in a SO or SU answer I get downvoted without an answer. How it goes around here apparently. :)

Comment: @Ian: Maybe I should have used the ruby syntax? ;-)

Comment: imagine super users using perl regular expressions, that's crazy

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you don't need a full editor, but often the best tools are found within one. [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) has full support for regular expressions and handles files and directories very well. Another that I haven't tried but heard good things about is [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: thanks, i'm already using Textmate and it's awesome, but not as a search-replace tool. "Why isn’t there a damn stop button?!!" (http://blog.johnjosephbachir.org/2007/10/01/interview-with-allan-odgaard-creator-of-textmate/) ;))