# What's a good find / replace utility for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, find, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X search and replace tool with regular expression support](https://superuser.com/questions/115348/mac-os-x-search-and-replace-tool-with-regular-expression-support)

I'm looking for a utility to do some multi-line find / replace with a GUI interface, possibly with some regex capabilities as well in OS X. Thanks!

ps: I really liked PowerGREP back when I used Windows - it was awesome! (powergrep, not windows :)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/115348/mac-os-x-search-and-replace-tool-with-regular-expression-support

Comment: Also, as a note. The "mac" tag is used when you're talking about Mac *hardware*. Use the "osx" tag when talking about software.

Comment: Funny. I looked for this question before posting but couldn't find anything similar. Thanks!